What is this 1980s thriller that contains surgery, anesthesia and music?
I'm trying to recall a novel I saw in the book store in the mid 1980s. The SF premise was a new surgical anesthesitic, which (unknown to everyone) didn't work.
It just made people seem to be asleep, though they were actually conscious of what was happening. I think the deal was that when it wore off, memories were suppressed but not eliminated, and could be triggered by (for example) hearing the music the surgeon had played during surgery, so people after surgery were randomly being exposed to that music and freaking out violently without knowing why.

That plot reminds me of Robin Cook, but I can't find anything in the 1980s by him that would fit.

It certainly is Cook-like

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curare "In the 1940s, [curare] was used on a few occasions during surgery as it was mistakenly thought to be an analgesic or anesthetic. The patients reported feeling the full intensity of the pain though they were not able to do anything about it since they were essentially paralyzed."

No doubt the inspiration for the novel.

Michael Palmer's Flashback (1988)


Toby is eight years old. He had a routine operation. It was fine. Now he's gone home to terror. Months have passed. But Toby still bursts into tortured screams. Because something is very wrong. Toby can remember every moment of the operation. All the trauma. All the pain. He relives every horrifying detail of surgery while he's awake. Now someone must expose the unspeakable truth about this hospital. Or else an innocent child will die. And he won't be the last. The next victim is being wheeled into surgery right now.

Music is the trigger for recalling the events of the surgery.

“So that’s where things stand,” he concluded. “The boy’s mother is certain that at least several times he was watching this children’s show when he had his seizures. It’s a show that features a version of ‘Greensleeves’—the same music you use in the operating room. If I could just get my hands on whatever it is you were using for anesthesia, I think I might be able to help that kid.”

This review does mention that the experimental anesthesia is to blame (and, of course, attempts to cover it up).
Found with search terms of site:goodreads.com fiction anesthesia surgery music

That's got to be it - a little later than I remembered, but it has all the details
